# Input file to java through command line

Tags: java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{          
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Input.txt"));
        }
```

I have to give input file through command line

```
java -cp  Projectfile.java < Input.txt
```

what change should I do in my program to fetch this file in `BufferedReader`?

Answer (score 1):

You pass it as command line argument

```
java -cp  Projectfile.java Input.txt
```

and access passed argument in `args[]`

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way. You may optionally include 'else' part. If you dont want else part then move the bufferreader statement in 'then' part. Run it as ->

```
java -cp . Projectfile Input.txt
```

Code ->

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, {      
        String file;    
        if ( args.length > 0 ) {
           file = args[0];
        }
        //Optionally you can define the file name if not supplied in java command. 
        else {
           file = "Input.txt"
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try the code below:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
}
```

During the execution of your program, you pass the file as argument but then you never use it. By using args[0], you will be using the argument that you passed on:

```
java -cp  Projectfile.java < Input.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all after initialising the BufferedReader class with "br" as its object, you need to write the following line

```
String str=br.readLine();
System.out.println(str);
```

Next you have to create a file Input.txt and place it in the same folder as that of your java file.

Next in the command prompt, write

```
javac Projectfile.java
Press Enter
java -cp . Projectfile < Input.txt
```

In this way it'll be done. Happy Coding Journey!!!